# Dataframe: Rowwise calculations

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to import an excel file into a dataframe. My dataframe (without the excel calculations) looks like this:

| Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | KPI (IF(SUM(JAN:APR)<0;0);SUM(JAN:APR)) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | -25 | -20 | 5 | 0 |
| 15 | 24 | 11 | -20 | 30 |

What is the best way to calculate the "KPI" column rowwise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
total     = df.loc[:, "Jan": "Apr"].sum(axis=1)
df["KPI"] = total.where(total > 0, other=0)
```

- get the total across needed columns
- keep it as is `where` it is > 0; put 0 to `other` places

or

```py
df["KPI"] = np.where(total > 0, total, 0)
```

or

```py
df["KPI"] = total * (total > 0)
```

to get

```py
In [162]: df
Out[162]:
   Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  KPI
0    5  -25  -20    5    0
1   15   24   11  -20   30
```

Answer (score 3):

Calculate row-wise sum, then call `mask` and pass a lambda function for `x>0` finally fill `NaN` values by zero.

```py
>>> df['KPI']=df.sum(1).mask(lambda x: x<0, 0)

   Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr   KPI
0    5  -25  -20    5   0.0
1   15   24   11  -20  30.0
```

**Better solution**: call `sum` then [`Series.clip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0/reference/api/pandas.Series.clip.html):

```py
df['KPI']=df.sum(1).clip(0)

   Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr   KPI
0    5  -25  -20    5   0.0
1   15   24   11  -20  30.0
```

Comment: Thank you for the edit, I didn't know we can use default/scalar values for `True` condition as well